# Using ExternalInterface with xml prettyPhoto url

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I've been trying to get to use the `ExternalInterface` through an xml file passing the variables for the info into Flash AS3 and can't work out how to get the data to change with each new selection made.

I managed to get it to call the `ExternalInterface` and use the initial data however I can't seem to get it to change.

I have in the HTML the following code for prettyPhoto lightbox which works as expected so far :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({hideflash: false, allow_resize: true, callback: function() {PAYPAL.apps.MiniCart.hide(null);}
});
});
function launchPrettyPhoto(urlContent) {
        $.prettyPhoto.open(urlContent);
     }
</script>
```

To call in the xml data I have a number of fields representing images, thumbs, title, description, and my url for the link to activate the lightbox, as below :

```
function loadXML(event:Event):void {
xml=new XML(event.target.data);
var total:Number=xml.pic.length();
for (var i:int = 0; i < total; i++) {
    thumbs[i]=xml.pic.thumb.text()[i];
    images[i]=xml.pic.image.text()[i];
    titles[i]=xml.pic.title.text()[i];
    descriptions[i]=xml.pic.desc.text()[i];
    wwwlink[i]=xml.pic.link.text()[i];
}
loadThumbs();
trace("loading thumbs");    
loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);
}
```

On each change of the image, data is updated via the following points whereby (ideally) the `ExternalInterface` 'url' should change as well, this I'm having problems with.

On each new selection the data is passed :

```
mainLoader.load(mainRequest);
title_txt.text = titles[theImg]; //Output title
desc_txt.text = descriptions[theImg]; Output Description
link_txt.htmlText = wwwlink[theImg]; Output URL
```

I have a button to call the function which initiates the `ExternalInterface` below :

```
function callPrettyPhoto(url:String):void{
trace("Calling lightbox");
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    // ExternalInterface calls function
    ExternalInterface.call("launchPrettyPhoto", url);
}
trace(ExternalInterface.call);
}

function initCall(event:MouseEvent):void {
// Call ExternalInterface
callPrettyPhoto(xml.pic.link.text());
}
```

As it stands, everything works well except that when I change image it fails to update or change the 'url', the rest works as in it updates everything accordingly and calls the lightbox as wanted.

From what I can see, the line below is the instigator as it seems to reference the first url in the xml file and fails to update with the rest :

```
callPrettyPhoto(xml.pic.link.text());
```

I've tried but can't quite wrestle it into submission and would appreciate your experienced input into where I'm going wrong.

**XML**

```
<images>
<pic>
    <image>images/01_00_00.jpg</image>
    <thumb>images/_t01_00_00.jpg</thumb>
    <title>First Picture</title>
    <desc>Typical description</desc>
    <link><![CDATA[http://www.website.com/_i01_00_01.html?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%]]></link>
</pic>
</images>
```

Comment: Can you post a **tl;dr** version? Your problem reminds pretty obscur to me...

Comment: Hi Florent, sorry for the ignorance but I'm new on here and just trying to get to grips with protocol and suchlike. What's a a tl;dr version?

Comment: **tl;dr** stands for _Too Long; Don't Read_. You should summarize your problem.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Sorry. (In short) I'm having problems getting the data from an xml file into a string for an ExternalInterface call to reference a prettyPhoto.js function.

I got it working to open the lightbox but it won't change on the item change suggesting it's in my selection method from the url.

Driving me mad as it's half working and I can't quite get it.

Comment: what does the XML structure look like

Comment: Hi @The_asMan, the xml is what I'd call typical :

    <images>
 <pic>
  <image>images/01_00_00.jpg</image>
  <thumb>images/_t01_00_00.jpg</thumb>
  <title>First Picture</title>
  <desc>Typical description</desc>
  <link><![CDATA[http://www.website.com/_i01_00_01.html?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%]]></link>
 </pic>
    </images>

There's extra after the .jpg for it being an iframe, otherwise standard.

It's getting it to reference the change after selection that it's not carrying through the url for the link which is the stress...

Comment: Don't you want something like xml.pic.image.text()

Comment: That's what I have : **callPrettyPhoto(xml.pic.link.text());** but it only seems to reference the first data taken from the xml file, if you change through the images etc it doesn't amend the data for the url/externalInterface. Everything else changes as it should, title, description, images etc but not the url for the call back.
I wondered if I would have to do some null reference check or clear it everytime?

Comment: Managed too fix it finally, I was along the right lines and came across another link similarly seeking for help with it as there seems to be quite a few people struggling with it. If anyone else needs help with this I'll be pleased to help out where I can.

I'm new on here and not too keen on seeing how some people build up points on here by belittling other peoples posts, comments or as it seems browsing through the latest posts and contributing nothing other than negative input, seems the old saying if you can't say anything good, don't say it may be relevant...

Comment: It might be good to post your solution below as an answer, then accept it. If someone else has the same problem, hopefully they will find your answer and vote it up to give you the credit :)

Comment: Shall do @Sunil, just re-working the code a little to post a full rundown on my blog as it seems quite a few people struggle with this.

Will update shortly... Θ)